# JavaScript function for string-format

Tags: javascript, string, format

I want to create a JavaScript function that take an string contains a format and another string and spill out the variables with in that format (In other words, inverse-format). 
For example,

```
func("a:b:c", "1:2:3") // {a: "1", b: "2", c: "3"}
func("x/y-z", "123/abc-x") // {x: "123", y: "abc", z: "x"}
func("x&y", "a-z") // undefined
```

Or something like that. 
Thank you!

Comment: Please provide what you’ve tried.

Comment: You could convert the format-string into a regular expression that matches that format. And then use that RegExp to match the other string and return the matched groups.

Comment: what about `func("a+b", "15+(1/3)")`? should that be `undefined` or `{a: "15", b: "(1/3)"}`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```js
const yourFunc = (arg1, arg2) => {
  let split1 = arg1.split(/[:/-]/);
  let split2 = arg2.split(/[:/-]/);

  let output = {};

  for(i=0; i<split1.length; i++){
    output[split1[i]] = split2[i] 
  }
  console.log(output);
  return output;
}


yourFunc("a:b:c", "1:2:3"); // {a: "1", b: "2", c: "3"}
yourFunc("x/y-z", "123/abc-x"); // {x: "123", y: "abc", z: "x"}
```

Comment: what about `yourFunc("a:b:c", "123/abc-x")`? This doesn't look right.

Comment: It's working fine on my browser, i get: {a: "123", b: "abc", c: "x"}

Comment: But that are completely different patterns. This should **not** match. You'd better split the strings by `/(\w+)/` and the odd indices contain the items to output, while the even indices should be identical

Comment: you are free to add your answer, thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it. Tell me if you see an error.

```
function inverseFormat(format, string) {
    let formater = format.replace(/[a-z]+/g, "([a-z|0-9]+)");
    let formatReg = new RegExp(formater, "g").exec(format);
    let stringReg = new RegExp(formater, "g").exec(string);
    let result = {};
    if (stringReg != null) {
        let foundFormat = formatReg[0];
        let foundString = stringReg[0];
        if (format.replace(foundFormat, foundString) == string) {
            for (let i = 1; i < stringReg.length; i++) {
                result[formatReg[i]] = stringReg[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using [named capture groups](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-named-groups) and [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), this becomes almost trivial:

```js
const escapeRegex = string => string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");

const func = (format, string) => string.match(
  new RegExp("^" + escapeRegex(format).replace(/[a-z]+/g, "(?<$&>\\w+)") + "$")
)?.groups;


[
  ["a:b:c", "1:2:3"],
  ["x/y-z", "123/abc-x"],
  ["x&y", "a-z"],
].forEach(([format, string]) => {
  console.log("format: %s\nstring: %s\nresult: %o", format, string, func(format, string));
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

Comment: Sorry that I'm late to this party. I got distracted.